# Did I burn the wrong .iso file?

Tags: installation, boot, graphics, livedvd

I have downloaded and burned the `.iso` on a MAC for installation on a Windows XP laptop that won't do much more than boot up. I am able to open the folder (from the DVD) on the XP laptop and it looks good (many folders and files). When I try to boot from the DVD, it gets caught up in repeating errors that say:

```
[###.###].[drm] nouveau 0000:01.00.0: Failed to idle channel 1
```

It will follow with the same message to channel 2. This is repeating until I power off the computer.

The computer on which I'm trying to boot the Ubuntu DVD is a Dell Inspiron E1705. The graphics card is not known. When I go into the display properties and look at the adapter type is says "VgaSave", manufacturer: Unknown. I do have obvious display issues but also can't connect to the Internet from this device either to attempt to load new drivers.

Is it possible that I have burned the wrong `.iso` file? Has anybody seen this?

It is a Dell Inspiron E1705. The graphics card is not known. When I go into the display properties and look at the adapter type is says "VgaSave", manufacturer: Unknown. I do have obvious display issues but also can't connect to the Internet from this device either to attempt to load new drivers.